# Filtering a list in dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have an opensource dataset that looks like this:

```
 > head(df)
# V1       V2 V3  V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14   V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22 V23 V24 V25

#1 240 20110101  1 260 50 50 70 50 NA  42   0   0   0   0 10217  56   8  95  20   7   1   0   0   0   0
#2 240 20110101  2 280 60 60 80 51 NA  42   0   0   0   0 10215  58   8  94  10   7   0   0   0   0   0
#3 240 20110101  3 280 60 60 80 51 NA  37   0   0   0   0 10211  60   8  91  2    7   0   0   0   0   0
#4 240 20110101  4 270 60 50 80 47 NA  37   0   0   0   0 10207  58   8  93  10   7   0   0   0   0   0
#5 240 20110101  5 260 50 50 70 53 NA  41   0   0   0   0 10202  61   8  92  NA   5   0   0   0   0   0
#6 240 20110101  6 270 50 50 70 51 34  39   0   0   0   0 10199  58   8  92  10   7   0   0   0   0   0
```

The second column contains the data. And as Im only interested in the weather results of particular data the first thing I would like to it to filter only the dates I need.

I have another df containing dates that looks like this:

```
> head(data,2)
  DATUM     TIJD
1 25-7-2014 18:30:00
2 26-7-2014 16:00:00
```

Im fetching the unique dates now from my second df using:

```
dates <- unique(data$DATUM)
```

And create a list ->

```
dates <- as.list(dates)
```

And now I try to filter the elements using dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
data_new <- filter(df, V2 %in% dates)
```

But this does not give me any records. I think something goed wrong at created the "dates" variable.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Several things: (1) variable `V2` does not exist in the data.frame `data` as you have written the problem. (2) you do not want a list of `dates` but rather a vector. (3) I don't see how the first data.frame `df` is relevant for your question. (4) You're not actually filtering anything. Since `dates` contains all unique dates from `data`, you should get the whole dataset back (once you correct your typo -- #1 above).

Comment: @Alex, thanks for your feedback. I made a type. I fetch the values from the data dataframe and am using these unique value to fillter df.

Comment: `df$V2` is not a date -- eg `is.Date(df$V2)`. `data$DATUM` is a date. You need to recode your datasets... This isn't a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), so I can't provide a functional solution.

Answer (score 2):

You want to work not with list but with a data frame.

I am copying the blog post that announced dplyr update:

**List-variables**

Data frames are usually made up of a list of atomic vectors that all have the same length. However, it’s also possible to have a variable that’s a list, which I call a list-variable. Because of data.frame()s complex coercion rules, the easiest way to create a data frame containing a list-column is with *data_frame()*:

```
data_frame(x = 1, y = list(1), z = list(list(1:5, "a", "b")))
> Source: local data frame [1 x 3]
> 
>   x        y         z
> 1 1 <dbl[1]> <list[3]>
```

http://blog.rstudio.org/2015/01/09/dplyr-0-4-0/

Answer (score 1):

How about using semijoin?

```
df %>%
  rename(DATUM = V2) %>%
  semi_join(data)
```